# Checking status of RAID on Ubuntu gives inconsistent output

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid

I tried to get status of RAID on Ubuntu using two commands. It appears that the output is  inconsistent. Basically I had configured a RAID using two devices and df shows entry for only /dev/md1. I had done this a long time back so am unsure if there is an issue. I should have been monitoring regularly. If there is an issue, how do I fix it?

**Output of first command: sudo mdadm -D /dev/md1**

```
 /dev/md1:
             Version : 1.2
       Creation Time : Wed Aug 29 18:00:43 2018
          Raid Level : raid1
          Array Size : 945379328 (901.58 GiB 968.07 GB)
       Used Dev Size : 945379328 (901.58 GiB 968.07 GB)
        Raid Devices : 2
       Total Devices : 2
         Persistence : Superblock is persistent
  
       Intent Bitmap : Internal
  
         Update Time : Sun Sep 18 16:00:11 2022
               State : clean 
      Active Devices : 2
     Working Devices : 2
      Failed Devices : 0
       Spare Devices : 0
  
  Consistency Policy : bitmap
  
                Name : august2018:1  (local to host august2018)
                UUID : b2f276cf:f094d73e:ffccdf64:ef2f21aa
              Events : 2794406
  
      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
         0       8       18        0      active sync   /dev/sdb2
         1       8        2        1      active sync   /dev/sda2
```

**Output of second command:  cat /proc/mdstat**

```
  Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
  md1 : active raid1 sda2[1] sdb2[0]
        945379328 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
        bitmap: 5/8 pages [20KB], 65536KB chunk
  
  md0 : active raid1 sda1[1]
        31232000 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [_U]
        
  unused devices: <none>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is not inconsistent. Both `/proc/mdstat` and `mdadm` shows that `md1` is just fine, and consists of two partitions.

`/proc/mdstat` *in addition* shows `md0`, consisting of two devices, but only *one* (`sda1`) active, and one missing.

Your physical devices is `sda` and `sdb`. A *guess* would be that `md0` is missing `sdb1` from the set, as you only have two devices (based on comments).

As for why `md0` is not shown in `df`: It's probably not mounted. Why that is? We don't know.

Comment: My question is: Does md1 represent the RAID with two devices and that both devices with the two partitions on them working fine? Or  does md0 and md1 represent two separate RAID devices and therefore expecting 4 physical devices? I have only two hard drives installed on this system. Never had more than that.

Comment: `md0` and `md1` is *two* raid devices. `md0` consists of `sda1` and one missing piece. `md1` consists of `sda2` and `sdb2`, with no missing pieces. `sda`  and `sdb` is your two physical devices.

Comment: So it appears that sdb1 is the missing piece. Any way I can diagnose further? I have accepted your answer anyway as it did answer my question.

Comment: It can be inferred, and given that you only have two devices, it's extremely probable - although you *can* make a md device with missing pieces if you want.